# Auth Attempt password Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, hash

In one project i am registering a user like this

```
private function insertUserCredentials(User $user, Request $request){
    ...
    $user->email = $request->email
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password );
    ...
}
```

And I login like this

```
if (!Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->emailLogin,
        'password' => $request->passwordLogin,
     ], $remember)
)
...
```

The password is inserted in db with hasing but in attemt i just have to retrieve the password the user has typed and everything works.

Now, if I register a user like this

```
    $Blowfish_Pre = '$2a$05$';
    $Blowfish_End = '$';
    $Allowed_Chars ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./';
    $Chars_Len = 63;
    $Salt_Length = 21;
    $salt = "";
    for($i=0; $i<$Salt_Length; $i++)
    {
        $salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$Chars_Len)];
    }
    $bcrypt_salt = $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End;
    $user->email = $request->registeremail;
    $user->password = crypt($request->password, $bcrypt_salt);
```

how can i use the Auth attempt? What do I have to change to make it work?

```
if (!Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->emailLogin,
        'password' => **here is my question**,
     ], $remember)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess easiest way to do that is to create your own method for that and authenticate user manually by using [`login()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#other-authentication-methods) method:

```
public function customAttempt($username, $password) {
    $user = User::find('username', $username);
    if (....checking for credentials.....) {
        // Authorize user.
        Auth::login($user, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but then i cant call the Auth functions, like Auth::user() var_dumps null

Comment: Oh! I dont know about Auth::login. Is this going to give me teh Auth functions ?

Comment: Ok it works! Thanks :) I will accept answer in 5 minutes